# Can the number of scc, "strong connected component" be increased if only one edge is added to graph?

Tags: graph

I have one question about `SCC` in Algorithm.
In `CLRS`, It is said that the number of `SCC` can be the same or decreased when one edge is added into a graph, no nodes complemented.
Then, I want to suppose a graph which has initially 4 nodes and 4 edges. 
The right graph is that one edge is added. [Two graph photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgP2k.jpg)

The left graph has one SCC. It is fine.
But, I have known that the right graph has not one SCCs, but two SCCs. : One is a triangle form, the other is just one node form.
Am I misunderstanding that concept?
Many web pages said the number of SCCs cannot be increased.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `version-control` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

This is an important point that would be easy to miss! A Strongly Connected Component (SCC) is defined to be a *maximal* set of vertices such that any two vertices in the set can reach each other. "Maximal" is a pretty innocuous word here, but it does a lot of heavy lifting.

Let's dig into how we define what a SCC is, and why the number in a given graph can only decrease or stay the same when we add an edge. My copy of CLRS defines a strongly connected component for a directed graph G = (V, E) as "a maximal set of vertices C ⊆ V such that for every pair of vertices *u* and *v* in C, we have both *u*⇝*v* and
*v*⇝*u*; that is, vertices *u* and *v* are reachable from each other."

There are a couple of important words in here that might fly under the radar. The ones that jump out to me are "maximal", "both", and "reachable". Let's look at these in the reverse order of how I presented them. First is reachable, which is about what you'd expect: a vertex is reachable from another vertex if there is some path between them - that is, if we can start at the first vertex and keep following adjacent edges until we arrive at the second. The next important word is "both" - not only is *u* reachable from *v*, but *v* is also reachable from *u*. We can start to get an understanding of why we'd care if two vertices are both reachable from each other. If
*v* is reachable from *u*, that means that *u* can *also* reach all of the nodes that *v* can reach - and if the converse is also the case, then *u* and *v* can both reach *all* of the same nodes. It is reasonable, in a sense, to think of them as being the same node in terms of where they can get to - ignoring, for a moment, all thoughts of efficiency, weight, or distance.

Now let's examine the idea of this set of vertices we take as our SCC being "maximal." The second graph posted does *not* have two SCCs, but only one. Why? Because the "node form" that you noticed isn't its own SCC - it's part of the single SCC that is made up of all of the vertices in the graph. A set of vertices is *maximal* if and only if we cannot include any other vertex in the graph without losing our property that every vertex in our set is reachable from every other vertex in our set - in some sense, we want as many nodes in our set as we can without breaking it. The "triangle form" that you point out isn't a maximal set, because we could add the "node form" to that set, and we would still be able to reach every node from every other node - in fact, because we're only interested in maximal sets, we *have* to add it, because otherwise we'd be leaving that node on the table.

So how do we know that the number of SCCs in a graph can only remain the same or decrease if we add an edge? We can show that these are
*possible* via examples. To show that the number of SCCs can stay the same, imagine a set of nodes that have a cycle. If we presume that there is some edge between nodes in this cycle that does not yet exist, we could add it, and we have not increased the number of SCCs because we haven't "gained access" to any nodes that we couldn't already reach. To show that the number can decrease, imagine that you have two vertices, with vertex *a* having a directed edge to vertex
*b*, so that we currently have two SCCs. If we add a directed edge from *b* to *a*, then we now only have a single SCC, the set {*a*,
*b*}.

How do we know that the number of SCCs can't increase? It's a very intuitive argument - first, notice that since all vertices in the graph are included in some SCC, the only way we could create more SCCs is if we split some of the existing ones up. However, we can never do this by adding an edge - if we look at our set C of all *u* and *v* such that *u*⇝*v* and *v*⇝*u*, adding a new edge cannot disrupt the fact that *u* and *v* are still reachable from each other for any *u* and *v* in our set. It is impossible to break up an existing SCC by adding an edge.

---

<sup>1</sup>Cormen, Thomas H., et al. Introduction to Algorithms. 3rd ed., MIT Press, 2009.

Comment: we can show we can only decrease *by "any amount"* by [this QA](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2407752/1059606) where the question also says when SCC number stays the same. ([contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction#) is also used in  [Boruvka’s Algorithm](https://community.wvu.edu/~krsubramani/courses/fa01/random/lecnotes/lec11/MST.pdf)).